# Kotlin String toDouble() function not parsing certain values?

Tags: java, kotlin, double, numberformatexception

why is my decimal String value not converting?! The value that gives the NumberFormatException works just fine when using java.lang.Double.parseDouble, but it is not recommended to use java Double's when working in Kotlin

[Image of results from using toDouble()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRNOE.png)

the double value is "﻿39.05166667"

Comment: What version of IDE and Kotlin do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string has a Unicode `u+FEFF` [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character at the beginning, which is defined as a "[Zero width no-break space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)". It's not even defined as whitespace, so `trim()` doesn't remove it!

I found that even when using `java.lang.Double.parseDouble`, it would fail. Maybe when you checked this, you inadvertently retyped the problematic part of the String.

You can check it by logging the length of your String and observing that it's one longer than expected.

I don't know how you got this character into your string (maybe from copying it from some HTML?), but you should be able to write a function to trim it to safely parse it:

```
fun String.fullTrim() = trim().replace("\uFEFF", "")

val number = "39.05166667".fullTrim().toDouble()
```

Comment: Wow I would have never guessed that in my life. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why `trim()`? This is not about leading or trailing whitespace (and would fail anyway if there was whitespace after the BOM).

Answer (score 2):

As kotlin documentation says, you can use "toDoubleOrNull()" to convert the string to a Double. It will return null if the string is not a valid representation of a Double.

Here's an example of when the value is invalid and when it's valid:

```
  fun main(args: Array) {

    val dstr1 = "1.234567899999"
    val double1: Double? = dstr1.toDouble()
    println(double1)
    // 1.234567899999

    val dstr2 = "A1.23";
    val double2: Double? = dstr2.toDouble()
    // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input 
  string: "A1.23"

    val double2: Double? = dstr2.toDoubleOrNull()
    println(double2)
    // null
  }
```

If the error persists, try a clean Android build. There is a bug on Kotlin's issue tracker that the Gradle build task didn't completely define everything correctly occasionally requiring clean builds. This has been fixed for the latest version of Kotlin. This issue have been answered here before: [String to Double on Android/Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309451/string-to-double-on-android-kotlin)